# Seperate radio buttons on table rows

Tags: html

I am dealing with a really weird error, this is my table:
[image: HTML Table]

But if i select something in the first row, and if i want to select something in the second row, then my selection in the first row goes away. so basically i need each row to be a separate radio group. Here is my code:

```
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped infoTable">

                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ownership</td>
                        <td>
                            <input  name="Test" type="radio" value="A" id="Same"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="B" id="Same1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="C"  id="Same2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="D"  id="Same3"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Management Control - Board Participation
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="A"  id="Same4"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="B"  id="Same5"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="C"  id="Same6"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Test" type="radio" value="D"  id="Same7"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Management Control - Employee Structure
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="A"  /></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="B"  /></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="C"  /></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="D"  /></label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are linked by their name value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep only name different for different set of radio button.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped infoTable">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ownership</td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="A" id="Same" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="B" id="Same1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="C" id="Same2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="D" id="Same3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Management Control - Board Participation
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test_1" type="radio" value="A" id="Same4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test_1" type="radio" value="B" id="Same5" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test_1" type="radio" value="C" id="Same6" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="Test_1" type="radio" value="D" id="Same7" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Management Control - Employee Structure
      </td>
      <td>
        <label><input name="Test_2" type="radio" value="A"  /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label><input name="Test_2" type="radio" value="B"  /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label><input name="Test_2" type="radio" value="C"  /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label><input name="Test_2" type="radio" value="D"  /></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only to change the name of inputs, like that.

```
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ownership</td>
                    <td>
                        <input  name="Test" type="radio" value="A" id="Same"  />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="B" id="Same1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="C"  id="Same2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Test" type="radio" value="D"  id="Same3"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Management Control - Board Participation
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Tes" type="radio" value="A"  id="Same4"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Tes" type="radio" value="B"  id="Same5"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Tes" type="radio" value="C"  id="Same6"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Tes" type="radio" value="D"  id="Same7"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Management Control - Employee Structure
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><input name="Te" type="radio" value="A"  /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><input name="Te" type="radio" value="B"  /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><input name="Te" type="radio" value="C"  /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><input name="Te" type="radio" value="D"  /></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```